# RetrievePropertiesAsync and COMException E_FAIL

Tags: c#, com, windows-runtime

I am having an issue on **one** machine. It is Windows 8.1 and x64, but it seems that it's not the real issue.

I have tested this code on devices and laptops running Windows 8 and 8.1 on all of the following platforms ARM, x86, and x64. **And only this one laptop throws the COMException.**

This code:

```cs
// Yes, I have checked the appropriate box in the manifest to access VideosLibrary.
StorageFolder vidFolder = KnownFolders.VideosLibrary;

var SystemFreeSpace = "System.FreeSpace";
var SystemCapacity = "System.Capacity";
var SystemPercentFull = "System.PercentFull";
var properties = new List<string>() { SystemFreeSpace, SystemCapacity, SystemPercentFull };

// THIS blows up on only one device. Though on Windows 8.1 I get null values (different issue).
var props = await vidFolder.RetrievePropertiesAsync(properties);
```

This is the exception message.

> **Error Code:**
>
> -2147467259
>
> **Error Message:**
>
> Error HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component.
>
> **Line Number:**
>
> mscorlib

So I am thingking that maybe this individual's Videos folder itself is the problem. The code works fine when I am trying to retrieve properties for a USB drive though.

Has anyone else run into this issue?

Comment: E_FAIL is an undiagnosable error code.  Asking for properties on a folder that only make sense on a drive surely ought to have something to do with it.

Comment: @HansPassant Thanks for the error code info. But your suspicion was not correct. Turns out that this user's VideosLibrary folder was corrupted. They had to delete the current VideoLibrary "folder" and then right-click on "Libraries > Restore Default libraries" in Windows Explorer. That fixed this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like the issue was because the user's VideosLibrary "folder" was corrupted. This may have happened due to the upgrade process from Win7 to Win8 to Win8.1 (just a theory).

The solution was: delete the old corrupted VideosLibrary and then open up a Windows Explorer browser and right-click on "Libraries > Restore default libraries".

[image: restore default libraries]